# Get the coordinate of a right edge of a PNG in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing

I am trying to find a way to detect the right edge of a png and add a label to it (like text "AB" in the   screenshot). The current way I am doing this is by adding a label on top of the image and then setting its left, right and top constraints.

Now this method works fine for 1 particular shoe, but if I add more shoes of different shapes and sizes then it obviously doesn't work and the label position isn't where I want it to be.

So is there anyway I can detect the right edge of the png image? So I can set the constraints relative to the image itself and not the image view? Not sure if that is possible.

Thank you

[image: Description of the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the shoes were quite different in shape so any code-only solution was not working well.

So I asked the designer to add a place holder text and then detected the frame using [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit). Then added my own label on top of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image size itself [from here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size). Then you can get aspect ratio of image itself, aspect ratio of `UIImageView` (using `.bounds` property) and perform some geometry calculations.

UPDATE: Code that will help you:

```js
let imageSize = yourImage.size
let imageViewSize = yourImageView.bounds.size


let imageAspectRatio = imageSize.height / imageSize.width
let imageViewAspectRatio = imageViewSize.height / imageViewSize.width

var rightOffset: CGFloat = 0

if imageAspectRatio > imageViewAspectRatio {
    let scaleCoef = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height
    let scaledWidth = imageSize.width * scaleCoef
    rightOffset = (imageViewSize.width - scaledWidth) / 2
}
```